# problemas al pasar datos json en flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Quisiera que de todos los datos de los usuarios que estan en un json solo me muestre uno, el que coincida con el usuario que esta logeado entonces para ver si me estaba pasando el correo con el que inicio sesion lo puse en el titulo del appbar y si me lo muestra, con esto quiero compararlo con los datos del json entonces hago una clase user lo mapeo para comparalo con el json pero me sigue imprimiendo todos los correos de todos los usuarios y no se que me falta, agradeceria mucho su ayuda apenas conozco flutter.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   MyApp({this.email});
  final String email;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('$email')
        ),
        body: JsonListView(email:email),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class User{
  final String email;
  User({this.email,});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)=>new User(
      email:json['us_correo'],
  );

  Map<String,dynamic>toJason()=>{
    "us_correo":email,
  };

  User userFromJson(String str){
    final jsonData=json.decode(str);
    return User.fromJson(jsonData);
  }
}

class JsonListView extends StatefulWidget {
  JsonListView({this.email});
  final String email;
  JsonListViewWidget createState() => JsonListViewWidget();
 }

class JsonListViewWidget extends State<JsonListView> {
  final String uri = 'getdata.php';
  Future<List<User>> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(uri);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      List<User> listOfUsers = items.map<User>((json) {
        return User.fromJson(json);
      }).toList();
      return listOfUsers;
    }
    else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data.');
    }
  }
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator()
            );
            return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data
                .map((data) => ListTile(
                      title: Text("Mostrar Datos"),
                      subtitle: Text("correo: "+data.email+""),
                    ))
                .toList(),
          );
        },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo el archivo `getData.php` retorna un JSON con los datos de todos los usuarios lo cual incluye correo electrónico, no puedes hacer consultas parciales de un JSON (alguien que me corriga si estoy equivocado).

Ten en cuenta:

1. Cada vez que un usuario haga una consulta para getData.php solo
   para desplegar su información, estara descargando un gran archivo con
   datos que nunca utilizara.
2. Por temas de seguirdad, no puedes confiar
   en el uso que los usarios le daran a tu aplicación por ende, una
   persona con los conocimientos necesarios podria tener acceso a toda
   la información de todos los usuarios, lo correcto seria tener reglas
   de seguridad en una parte del servidor que prevengan esto.

Espero que esto te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: tienes razón por temas de seguridad es malo lo que trato de hacer me falta mucho por aprender muchas gracias